# Hibernate - Spring MVC - llegal attempt to associate a collection with two open sessions

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-mvc

There are are many questions of same type, but none works for me.

I have Spring MVC hibernate application.

Here are my two model classes

**Config.java**

```
public class Config  implements java.io.Serializable {

    private Integer configId;
    private String configName;
    private Set<ConfigFields> ConfigFieldses = new HashSet<ConfigFields>(0);

    //getters and setters

    @OneToMany(cascade=CascadeType.ALL, fetch=FetchType.EAGER, mappedBy="configuration")
    public Set<ConfigFields> getConfigFieldses() {
            return this.ConfigFieldses;
    }

    public void setConfigFieldses(Set<ConfigFields> ConfigFieldses) {
            this.ConfigFieldses = ConfigFieldses;
    }
}
```

**ConfigFields.java**

```
public class ConfigFields  implements java.io.Serializable {


    private Integer configFieldId;
    private Confign config;
    private String configFieldName;

    //getteres and setters

    @XmlTransient
    @ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name="ConfigId")
    public Config getConfig() {
        return this.config;
    }

    public void setConfig(Config configu) {
        this.config = config;
    }
}
```

Here is **GenericHibernateDao.java**

```
@Repository
@Transactional
public class GenericHibernateDao<T extends Serializable>
implements GenericDao<T>{

    @Resource
        protected SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    @Override
    public void insert(T transientInstance) {
        sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().persist(transientInstance);
    }

    @Override
    public void update(T instance) {
        sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().saveOrUpdate(instance);
    }

    @Override
    public void delete(T persistentInstance) {
        sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().delete(persistentInstance);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    @Override
    public T merge(Serializable detachedInstance) {
        return (T) sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().merge(detachedInstance);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    @Override
    public T findById(Class<?> clazz, Serializable id) {
        T t= (T) sessionFactory.openSession().get(clazz, id);
        return t;
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public  List<T> findByNamedQuery(Class<T> clazz, String queryName, Map<String, Object> queryParams) {
        Query namedQuery = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().getNamedQuery(queryName);

        for (String s : queryParams.keySet()) {
            namedQuery.setParameter(s, queryParams.get(s));
        }

        return namedQuery.list();
    }

}
```

In my controller I have this method

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/deleteConfig/{configId}", method = RequestMethod.POST)
@ResponseBody
@Transactional
public String deleteConfiguration(@PathVariable Integer configId, HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException {
    try {
        Config config=configService.findById(configId);

        logger.info("Deleting configuration...");
        configService.delete(config);

    } catch(Exception e) {
        logger.debug(e.getMessage());
        response.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_BAD_REQUEST);
    }

    return "success";
}
```

My test case

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@WebAppConfiguration("classpath:webapptest")
@ContextConfiguration(locations = {"classpath:test-applicationcontext.xml"})
public class ConfigurationsControllerTest {

    private MockMvc springMvc;

    @Autowired
    WebApplicationContext wContext;

    @Before
    public void init() throws Exception {
        springMvc = MockMvcBuilders.webAppContextSetup(wContext).build();
    }

    @Test
    public void deleteConfiguration() throws Exception {
        ResultActions resultActions=springMvc.perform(MockMvcRequestBuilders.post("/deleteConfig/117").accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON));
        resultActions.andDo(MockMvcResultHandlers.print());
        resultActions.andExpect(MockMvcResultMatchers.status().isOk());
    }

}
```

When I run the testcase in console, logger showing

```
Illegal attempt to associate a collection with two open sessions
```

And JUnit test case stacktrace is

```
org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.transaction.UnexpectedRollbackException: JTA transaction unexpectedly rolled back (maybe due to a timeout); nested exception is bitronix.tm.internal.BitronixRollbackException: transaction was marked as rollback only and has been rolled back
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:932)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:827)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:641)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:801)
    at org.springframework.test.web.servlet.TestDispatcherServlet.service(TestDispatcherServlet.java:66)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
    at org.springframework.mock.web.MockFilterChain$ServletFilterProxy.doFilter(MockFilterChain.java:168)
```

In **Config** class, I have **Set**  which is set to **CASCADE ALL**. SO I am able to insert set of configfields while inserting config too. But now I want to delete by passing config object. So it should delete 1 row from  config table and few rows from configfields table based on configId.

What is wrong here? And how to solve without affecting application(I mean insert)

Comment: Is your controller method really as you posted here? It looks like you're retrieving a `config` object somewhere, keeping a reference to it, and then trying to use it in a subsequent request, and the two variables you mentioned there look like a possible mismatch.

Comment: Your findById method is flawed. Never use `openSession()` but use `getCurrentSession()`. Next to that you are putting business logic inside your controller, this really belongs in a service method which would be marked with `@Transactional`.

Comment: And, really, injecting the `Session` (or `EntityManager`) instead of `SessionFactory` is usually a safer and cleaner approach.

Comment: @chrylis OOps. That was a typing mistake. I have edited

Comment: @M.Deinum I have service classes and that only I am calling. In this controller I have some other transactions. So I am putting `Transactional`

Comment: Business logic belongs in a service not in a controller. Create a new service put it in there, not in a controller. You are now basically making your web layer transactional not to mention the fact that this piece of code is now not reusable (without refactoring).

Comment: @M.Deinum Thanks. It worked. Earlier it was `getCurrentSession()`. I changed it ti openSession when I got some error earlier and then forgot to change back. :)

Comment: I have service. You can see I am calling `configService.findById` and `configService.delete`. But in controller I have some other logics after deleting this. And I want the whole to be in a transaction :)

Comment: I just have to comment that I get way more amusement than I should from the member name `ConfigFieldses`